# Debug an Excel template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, excel, templates

I have been working on an Excel 2010 template for some time and I am quite satisfied with it. But the problem is that when I save the file and then reopen it, sometimes Excel crashes and I have no way to know what happens...

The issue is that it is easy to debug the template at its first start as it always debug with a fresh template. But it is not possible to debug the file when you reopen it from the explorer. I want to analyse the behavior of the program when I open a file created from the original template. Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ucodia, does the file has any macros that run on startUp? have you tried opening the file with `application.enableevents` set to False?

Comment: I don't use macro, it is a simple C# Excel template project. And also I make a heavy use of Worksheet ad Workbook events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself. When I open my Excel file from the explorer, I just need to attach the EXCEL.EXE process to Visual Studio in Tools > Attach to Process...

That was that simple. The only drawback is that I cannot hook on the startup events as Excel needs to appear in the processes list to be attached to Visual Studio.